# is it possible to make a animated moving widget on Android home-screen?

Tags: android

just want to ask a very basic technical question here about android.
well i just imagine if i can make a sort of application that doesn't run on activity, but running a Service to make some kind of screensaver widget that animated and moving object on home screen, probably like pacman eating the shortcuts. is it possible?

Comment: for what version, I think (not completely sure) that widgets before ICS were not really powerfull?

Comment: well, maybe ICS and above? i dunno i just concern it's getting work whatever the api is...

Answer (score 0):

Looked into this a while back. There is a Mario hitting a coin example floating around that does this (https://code.google.com/p/mario-coin-block/). However, from everything I've read it is very hacky and likely to have horrible performance/battery drain.

Comment: sorry, it most likely but it doesn't. i expected the mario walking across the screen and then jump and hit the box. it seems like that widget just occupy the place exactly where it lies, it doesn't move to other widget tiles or across the whole screen like i want hhhh thnx btw